# Get LinkedIn Response Empty while login with linkedin - specific user case

Tags: android, linkedin-api

Issue in Android app not using android sdk.

Created an App through  LinkedIn Developer , App Enviornment : Live,

- Case 1 : A user open android app and click on Login with linked in
  and enter credential, Allow permission and able to Navigate
  successfully .
- Case 2 : A user open android app and click on Login with linked in
  and enter credential, Allow permission but not able to Navigate
  successfully and get response null.

2nd user also able to login successfully but getting null response for them.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue and second user is getting an access token with expiry time of 0. Same device using different accounts works fine. The issue is specific to two users.